# How to predict various opponents' attacks?

Tags: risen

**Rage-filled Rant**

I've recently started playing Risen, and even tho it's an amazing game with good visuals, design, interaction and character development, very often the combat difficulty is bat-shit-crazy. I managed to keep playing untill i've stumbled upon my first giant scorpions, and fighting even one of these (obviously losing) makes me want to ram my head through the wall into the neighbouring appartment and scream like **[this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Pqj1dzzL2g)**. >:[

I've been playing Monster Hunter a lot, so im used to the type of combat that this game has (dodge/block/create opening, strike, repeat), but as far as I notice, all those swords and maces flying at your face/gut/crotch/knee are lightning fast and the patterns are non-existant.

**Question**

Is there any way to predict the attacks of one's opponents (so you know when to dodge and parry)? And if it matters, when is it best to use back-step dodge vs side-step dodge vs simple block?

Comment: if I remember correctly (its been a while since I played Risen) its almost never worth it to block, and I back-step dodge a lot.

Comment: Backstep? Against scorpions at least, that kind of makes it hard to actually fight them, since every time they dont block an attack, they just backstep themselves.

Comment: then you should fill them with arrows ;)

Comment: There are actually patterns (are just a bit harder to see). Finished risen long time ago, but if I remember right the scorpion had something like: atk, w8, w8, atk, w8, atk atk and repeat. Note: Moving and/or attacking resets the pattern (I'm guessing that's what confuses you). If you played gothic... most patterns are similar. As a quick note... after you have a decent level the game becomes significantly easier. Also found this for you (maybe it will help): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovsqovkk0AM

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about actually predicting attacks (like, by reading a tell in an enemy's movement), but a strategy I use with great efficiency is to block, waiting for a first attack, then step aside as your opponent usually tries to attack at least once more and strike as he miserably misses you.

Comment: That's the problem. I know how to dodge the attacks, and i'm used to it. I simply have no idea how i'm predicting them xD